# How to remove duplicates in all column of excel sheet until value in first column is changed

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in excel sheet data is based on column A value that is i want to delete duplicates from all other column including Column A until value in column A is changed,after this i want all unique value in other column should comma separated in single cell.Data and required output is given below.

Input

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nY6gy.png)

Output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjvoA.png)

Now i add following code and code is removing duplicate but not moving unique in one line

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
```

'UpdatebyExtendoffice20160918

```
Dim xRow As Long
Dim xCol As Long
Dim xrg As Range
Dim xl As Long
On Error Resume Next
Set xrg = Application.InputBox("Select a range:", "Kutools for Excel", _
                                ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.AddressLocal, , , , , 8)

xRow = xrg.Rows.Count + xrg.Row - 1
xCol = xrg.Column
'MsgBox xRow & ":" & xCol
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For xl = xRow To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(xl, xCol) = Cells(xl - 1, xCol) Then
        Cells(xl, xCol) = ""
    End If
Next xl
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Anyone have idea regarding this issue.

Comment: you want to delete data on the basis of first column, and keep fields position same?

Comment: yes and then move all values in one row with comma between each field